# ORA-00130: invalid listener address, configure failure

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe, slackware

In Slackware distributive after installing 11.2 package tried configuring as

```
sudo /etc/rc.d/rc.oracle-xe configure
```

CloneRmanRestore.log is fine and in cloneDBCreation.log has some errors

```
...
    ORA-00119: invalid specification for system parameter LOCAL_LISTENER
    ORA-00130: invalid listener address '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=black)(PORT=1521))'
...
```

My hostname -i and hostname -f give

```
127.0.0.1
```

and

```
black
```

results.

```
tnsping black:1521 is OK.
```

Here is listener.ora, tnsname.ora and ${ORACLE_HOME}/config/scripts/init.ora

```
#  SID_LIST_LOCAL_LISTENER =
#  (SID_LIST =
#    (SID_DESC =
#      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
#      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
#      (PROGRAM = extproc)
#    )
#  )
# use LOCAL_LISTENER instead default LISTENER
LOCAL_LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
#       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = black)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

tnsname.ora

```
    XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
#    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = black)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

init.ora

```
    ...
*.local_listener="(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=127.0.0.1) (PORT=1521))"
local_listener="(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=127.0.0.1) (PORT=1521))"
```

I've tried a static listener as in default setting, then tried dynamic service registration by commenting in listener.ora and redefining default LISTENER to LOCAL_LISTENER. Applying

```
lsnrctl status LOCAL_LISTENER
```

after failed configuring gives

```
...
        ------------------------
Alias                     LOCAL_LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
...
Listening Endpoints Summary...
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
    Services Summary...
    Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
      Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    The command completed successfully
```

Help to solve issue, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps it should help to resolve your problem.

--Login as sysdba

```
$sqlplu / as sysdba
```

--Creating pfile from current spfile

```
SQL>create pfile='/home/oracle/mypfile.ora' from spfile;
```

--Keep a backup copy just for your refernece.

```
$cp /home/oracle/mypfile.ora /home/oracle/mypfile.ora.backup
```

Now, open newly created pfile, /home/oracle/mypfile.ora and remove local_listenr='listener_' and save it.

--shutdown the database

```
SQL>Shutdown
```

--startup database using new pfile

```
SQL>startup nomount pfile='/home/oracle/mypfile.ora'
```

--create server spfile from pfile

```
SQL>create spfile from pfile;
```

--shutdown database, if already in shutdown then it's fine.

```
SQL>Shutdown
```

--start the database.

```
SQL>startup
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've reconfiguring successfully script by manual do XE.sql in init directory. By following above loading spfile is fine. But when do 
select table_name from user_tables;
have 
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only

Comment: Even more cant do simply
**sqlplus system/some_secret_passwd@XE**
have a
**ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress**

Comment: Seems that your database is not in open state, you can shutdown database in immediate (or abort mode in worst case), and start db in normal mode. If you still getting same issue, alert log can give more details, in your case check alert_xe.log and share the latest error messages. Thanks.

Comment: Shutdown is fine. When just **startup** have **ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/system.dbf'
ORA-01206: file is not part of this database - wrong database id** and others errors (ORA-01186,ORA-01122, ORA-01221). 

When starts up with pfile option, all errors go away, but select has the same failure.

Comment: Startup got proper pfile, it reaches to nomount mode. Also, it finds correct control file, it's promoted to mount mode. As a final step, it verifies the datafiles as recorded by control file to open the database.

As per the last error message, database id in the .dbf file header and control file doesn't match. Here, wayout is to restore a copy of correct datafile and required to recover the database.